# Ionic 2 storage not working on iOS

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, storage

Ionic 2 storage not working on ios but working on Android. I am using this one `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';` to store data locally.

I made sample like this

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  setData() {
    // set a key/value
    storage.set('username', 'johndoe');
  }
  getData() {
    // get a key/value pair
    storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      alert('Your username is', val);
    });
  }
}
```

It works perfectly on Android. But when I try to build on iOS, it doesn't work. Data is not showing. Some recommendation on how to store persistent data in ionic 2 that works perfectly on android and iOS platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't see your main module definition, so I'll touch on that point first. In your main app module you need to have an import for `IoinicStorageModule` and then you need to put this in your `imports` section:

```
imports:[IonicStorageModule.forRoot({'yourappname'})]
```

Second, I don't see you checking to see if storage is ready, and you should probably do that too:

```
this.storage.ready()
    .then(() => {
        this.storage.set(key, value);
    });
```

Lastly, your local storage issues can easily be solved with this simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
    constructor(private storage: Storage){
    }

    public setValue(key: string, value: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.storage.ready()
            .then(() => {
                return this.storage.set(key, value)
                    .catch(() => {
                        return null;
                });
            });
        //TODO: Handle storage not being available
    }

    public getValue(key: string): Promise<string> {
        return this.storage.ready()
            .then(() => {
                return this.storage.get(key)
                    .catch(() => {
                        return null;
                    });
            });
        //TODO: Handle storage not being available
    }
}
```

I use this on a daily basis. Don't forget to wrap some unit tests around it.

Comment: I already have 'IoinicStorageModule' so I go straight to the point.
Anyway, Thank you for that. I'll try that later.  Is that code working on iOS?   did you test it?

Comment: According to the docs (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) it is cross-platform and choose the best solution for each platform. I don't have access to iOS at this time, but it will be tested before the app goes out on the app stores.

Comment: Very interesting. You might file a bug request with the folks over at Ionic because it is supposed to. Knowing that it doesn't work for you, I'll be sure to test it thoroughly before release.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll install SQLite plugin then you'll not have any issue on iOS too.

Here is the [**SQLite**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/) plugin.

> When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using
>   SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based
>   databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage
>   and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low
>   disk-space situations.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try that. But i want @ionic/storage because it is easy to use only that it doesn't work on ios. So sad :(